# facing runtime error on online compiler and not on command prompt

Tags: java, runtime

I am not getting why this java code works fine in command prompt and not in online compiler and getting runtime error.
I tried to find out the reason on web but didn't find suitable answer.

its getiing runtime error-

```
       Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at head.main(Main.java:9)
```

code is-

```
       import java.util.*;


       class head
         {
       public static void main(String arg[])
        {
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int c1=0,c2=0;
        int i;
        while(n>0)
        {
        int l=sc.nextInt();
        String str=sc.next();

        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
        char ch=str.charAt(i);
        if(ch=='i'||ch=='I') 
        c1++;
          if(ch=='y'||ch=='Y')
         c2++;
         } 
         if(c1>0)
         System.out.println("INDIAN");
        else if(c2>0)
        System.out.println("NOT INDIAN");
        else 
        System.out.println("NOT SURE");
        c1=0;
        c2=0;
        n--;
        }
       }
     }
```

Comment: Are you supplying the online compiler with input to stdin?

Comment: What is the line that throws the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not checking scanner if it has more data to scan, that's why you're getting exception.

See the `throwFor` method defined in Scanner below.

```
// If we are at the end of input then NoSuchElement;
// If there is still input left then InputMismatch
private void throwFor() {
    skipped = false;
    if ((sourceClosed) && (position == buf.limit()))
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    else
        throw new InputMismatchException();
}
```

In the comments it says that this is called when end of input has been reached.

Correct usage of Scanner is always something like below

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputstream);

while(scan.hasNext()) {
    //read data
}
```

It's same as reading a file, you've to check for EOF(end of file) every time you try to read.

In your code correction can be applied like following.

```
import java.util.*;

class head {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
        int i;
        while (n > 0) {
            //check for EOF
            if(!sc.hasNext()) {
                break;
            }
            int l = sc.nextInt();
            String str = sc.next();

            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                char ch = str.charAt(i);
                if (ch == 'i' || ch == 'I')
                    c1++;
                if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
                    c2++;
            }
            if (c1 > 0)
                System.out.println("INDIAN");
            else if (c2 > 0)
                System.out.println("NOT INDIAN");
            else
                System.out.println("NOT SURE");
            c1 = 0;
            c2 = 0;
            n--;
        }
    }
}
```